# Add a function in Column (Average) using Workbench

Tags: mysql, function, triggers, average

I am new to SQL and MySQL and I am trying to find a way to create an column in one of my tables with an average of another column's input.

I have a database with professors, these teach each year a theoretical and practical class. For each classes they receive a score. Now, I have two tables, one for theoretical classes and another for practical classes, with all scores they have received throughout the years.

But I want a new table that can have the average of all the scores a professor has received. And I don't know how to tell the program to do the average WHERE the values for faculty_id are the same. (There is a diagram bellow to understand the idea).

I'd also like a trigger to update my information as I add new evaluations for new classes.

If anyone can help me I'd appreciate it! Thank you! :)
[Diagram of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWMzm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the question meaning you want to do this for practical and theory table. You can get professor by example. CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT professor_table.name, AVG(practical_eval_table.evaluation) AS practical_avg, FROM professor_table, practical_table, practical_eval_table WHERE professor_table.I'd=practical_eval_table.prof_id AND practical_table.id=practical_eval_table.practical_id
This  is how you gonna get average score for practical course a particular professor has created over the years and you can use same approach for the theory course too. Hope this help

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and see if I can make it work.

Comment: I did what you said. But, the view only has one row... here is my code: CREATE VIEW practical_avg_eval AS 
SELECT professors.professors_id,
 AVG(pevaluation.Evaluation) AS practical_Avg
FROM professors, pevaluation, practicalcourses
WHERE professors.professors_id=pevaluation.professors_id AND
practicalcourses.pcourse_id=pevaluation.pcourse_id

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view where you can add  avg(column_name) or you can create a virtual average column avg(column_name) which will keep the incoming score if you are using mysql v5.9 or higher

Comment: Thank you. Then how would I select the professors ? Because I want an average of all classes an individual professor has lectures. so I would have to make an average of the values where professor_id are the same across rows. And I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Average returns one row. That's  how database works. It return one row for each Prof